# How to redirect CodeIgniter main route to a specific route?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make sure the CodeIgniter 4 main route isn't redirected to the `welcome_message` view of the `index()` method in `Home.php`. I want that it be redirected to `http://localhost:8080/pacient/index` because of `$routes->get('pacient/index', [PacientController::class, 'index']);`.

```
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;
use App\Controllers\Home;
use App\Controllers\PacientController;

/**
 * @var RouteCollection $routes
 */

 $routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');

$routes->get('/', 'Home::index'); // No main route more

$routes->get('pacient/index', [PacientController::class, 'index']); // Main route expected
$routes->get('pacient/create', [PacientController::class, 'create']);
$routes->get('pacient/search', [PacientController::class, 'search']);
$routes->post('pacient/store', [PacientController::class, 'store']);
$routes->get('pacient/view/(:num)', [PacientController::class, 'view']);
$routes->get('pacient/edit/(:num)', [PacientController::class, 'edit']);
$routes->post('pacient/update/(:num)', [PacientController::class, 'update']);
$routes->delete('pacient/delete/(:num)', [PacientController::class, 'delete']);
```

Comment: $routes->get('/', [PacientController::class, 'index']); // Change the default route to PacientController::index